# How to display a rect shape created in a class?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a frogger game and am trying to create logs for the player to land on. To do this I decided to write a class that can do this for all logs created. I am having difficulty figuring out how to display these shapes as I cannot use the blit method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
import sys, pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen_height = 750
screen_width = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Frogger")
FPS = 200

player = pygame.image.load('frog.bmp')
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_rect.left = 300 + 1
player_rect.top = screen_height - 74

#For player movement
up_movements = 0
down_movements = 0
left_movements = 0 
right_movements = 0
up_movement = False
down_movement = False
left_movement = False
right_movement = False

x_logs = [1, 301, 601]
y_logs = [149, 224, 299, 374, 449, 524, 599, 674]
log_width = 74
log_height = 74
logs_created = []

class Log():

    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.direction = direction
        self.log = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0),(self.x, self.y, log_width, log_height))

    def move_log(self):
        if self.direction == 'right':
            self.x += 5
        if self.direction == 'left':
            self.x -= 5
        self.log

    def draw_new_logs(self): # To address the issue of infinitely spawning in logs, put the if statements in the main game loop and only have it run this method if it meets the requirements
        if self.direction == 'right':
            if self.log.right > screen_width:
                logs_created.append(Log(-73, self.y, log_width, log_height))
            #Delete log if it exceeds boundary
            if self.log.left > screen_width:
                logs_created.remove(self.log)

        if self.direction == 'left':
            if self.log.left < 0:
                logs_created.append(Log(749, self.y, log_width, log_height))
            #Delete log if it exceeds boundary  
            if self.log.right < 0:
                logs_created.remove(self.log)


for x in x_logs:
    for y in y_logs:
        if (y_logs.index(y) % 2) == 0: 
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'left'))
        else:
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'right')) 

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 119, 190))
    starting_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0, 675, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    finish_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0,0, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    screen.blit(player, player_rect)

    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    for item in logs_created:
        item.move_log()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                down_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                left_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right_movement = True

        #Movements
    if up_movement == True:
        if player_rect.top > 1:
            if up_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y -= 15
                up_movements += 15
            else:
                up_movements = 0
                up_movement = False
        else:
            up_movement = False
            up_movements = 0
    if down_movement == True:
        if player_rect.bottom <= screen_height - 1:
            if down_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y += 15
                down_movements += 15
            else:
                down_movements = 0
                down_movement = False
        else:
            down_movement = False
            down_movements = 0

    if left_movement == True:
        if player_rect.left > 1:
            if left_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x -= 15
                left_movements += 15
                print(player_rect.left)
            else:
                left_movements = 0
                left_movement = False
    if right_movement == True:
        if player_rect.right <= screen_width - 1:
            if right_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x += 15
                right_movements += 15
            else:
                right_movements = 0
                right_movement = False

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) does not construct some kind of drawable object (like a `Surface`), it draws a rectangle on a surface. You have to use `pygame.draw.rect()` instead of `pygame.Surface.blit()`, rather than instead of `pygame.image.load()`.
The return value of [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) is a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object. A `pygame.Rect` just contains the location and size of a rectangle.
Instead of drawing a rectangle in the constructor of `Log`, you have to add a `draw` method to the class `Log`, which draws a rectangle on the screen:

```py
class Log():

    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.direction = direction

    def move_log(self):
        if self.direction == 'right':
            self.x += 5
        if self.direction == 'left':
            self.x -= 5

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0),(self.x, self.y, log_width, log_height))
```

Add the initial `Log` objects to the list `logs_created`, before the main application loop:

```py
x_logs = [1, 301, 601]
y_logs = [149, 224, 299, 374, 449, 524, 599, 674]
logs_created = []

for x in x_logs:
    for y in y_logs:
        logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'right'))
```

Move and draw all the `Log` objects in `logs_created`, in the main application loop:

```py
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 119, 190))
    starting_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0, 675, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    finish_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0,0, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    screen.blit(player, player_rect)

    # draw logs
    for log in logs_created:
        log.draw()

    # [...]

    # move logs
    for log in logs_created:
        log.move()
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and help